# Passing multiple parameters into a Table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table valued function as below. When I am trying to pass more than one parameter at the same time I am getting a error like "Function has too many arguments specified" .

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCompanyUsers](@CompanyId  BIGINT)    
RETURNS @Users TABLE (Id BIGINT,Contact NVarchar(4000)) 
AS 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO @Users(Id,Contact)
SELECT [Id]
  ,ISNULL([FirstName],'')+' ' +ISNULL([LastName],'') AS [Contact]
FROM [dbo].[CompanyAddressesContacts]
WHERE  [CompanyId]=@CompanyId
ORDER BY ISNULL([FirstName],'')+' ' +ISNULL([LastName],'')

RETURN 

END
```

What modifications I require in the above code so that it allows multiple values and I need to use the function in  a "WHERE" condition in my dataset.

```
WHERE(Document_RFIs.CreatedBy IN
               (SELECT Id FROM dbo.GetCompanyUsers(@CompanyId)))
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a join like this? INNER JOIN dbo.GetCompanyUsers(@CompanyId) GCU ON GCU.Id = Document_RFIs.CreatedBy

Comment: how many parameters are you passing?

Comment: @Raphael Yes I tried . But I am getting the same error "Procedure or Function has too many arguments specified"

Comment: Number of parameters can vary depending on the no of companies selected . It can vary between 1 to many   

e.g. dbo.GetCompanyUsers(23,24,25)

Comment: How are the companyid values being passed into sql?  Number of parameters cannot vary in SQL.  Where are they being `selected`?

Comment: @dav1dsm1th I am sorry. To be clear . There is only one parameter companyId but it can hold multiple values. A user can select multiple companies in a drop down and from there the IDs of the selected companies are captured and passed into this parameter. Therefore, this parameter can hold multiple values and I want my function to be modified in order to operate on multiple values passed into a single parameter(CompanyId). The values passed are comma separated

Comment: so the parameter needs to be a varchar long enough to hold all the values.  you then parse the string and break out the values into a temp table or a table valued variable.  then you `join` to this - or use an `exists` - in a select to get what you want.  Are you calling a stored procedure that then calls your function?

Comment: @dav1dsm1th No I am using this function in a query, not a stored procedure . I followed ur instruction but still no fruit.

Comment: see if my answer helps - it shows the building blocks you need to use - you can pick where you use each part (the function is not really necessary).

Answer (score 0):

This may help (but the fundamental problem is - passing a comma delimited string is something to be avoided unless absolutely necessary - which explains why you have received so few answers):-

```
--set nocount on

--create table #Document_RFIs (
--  CreatedBy varchar(50),
--  columna varchar(50),
--  columnb varchar(50),
--  columnc varchar(50)

--)
--insert into #Document_RFIs values 
--  ('albert einstein','another','value',null),
--  ('marie curie','some',null,'tuna'),
--  ('isaac newton','why','not','provide'),
--  ('kepler','some','test','data'),
--  ('robert boyle','with','your','question'),
--  ('john dalton','it',null,'would'),
--  ('enrico fermi','make','helping','you'),
--  ('peter higgs','so','much','easier')

--create table #CompanyAddressesContacts (
--  companyid int,
--  firstname varchar(50),
--  lastname varchar(50)
--)
--insert into #CompanyAddressesContacts values (22,'albert','einstein')
--insert into #CompanyAddressesContacts values (23,'marie','curie')
--insert into #CompanyAddressesContacts values (23,'isaac','newton')
--insert into #CompanyAddressesContacts values (24,null,'kepler')
--insert into #CompanyAddressesContacts values (25,'robert','boyle')
--insert into #CompanyAddressesContacts values (25,'enrico','fermi')
--insert into #CompanyAddressesContacts values (26,'peter','higgs')

declare @ids varchar(1024)

set @ids='23,24,25'

create table #id (
    companyid int
)

declare @pos int

while DATALENGTH(@ids)>0 begin
    set @pos=charindex(',',@ids)
    if @pos>0 begin
        insert into #id values (left(@ids,@pos-1))
        set @ids=SUBSTRING(@ids,@pos+1,DATALENGTH(@ids))
    end else begin
        insert into #id values (@ids)
        set @ids=''
    end
end

select d.*
from #Document_RFIs d
where exists(
    select cac.*
    from #CompanyAddressesContacts cac
    join #id i on i.companyid=cac.companyid
    where isnull(cac.firstname+' ','')+isnull(cac.lastname,'')=d.CreatedBy
)

--drop table #id
--drop table #Document_RFIs
--drop table #CompanyAddressesContacts
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

First convert your @CompanyId to rows

```
WITH CompanyIds AS (
    SELECT Id
    FROM CompanyTable -- Same as the source of the @CompanyId
    WHERE Id IN (@CompanyId)
)
```

Then extract all users

```
,Users AS (
     SELECT UserId
     FROM CompanyIds
         CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT Id AS UserId
             FROM dbo.GetCompanyUsers(CompanyIds.Id)
         ) AS CA1
 )
```

And then use it in the where statement

```
WHERE Document_RFIs.CreatedBy IN (SELECT UserId 
                                  FROM Users)
```