# Pass multiple values of same input type to BigQuery Table Valued Function

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

Lets say I have a table value function (TVF) like

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE FUNCTION Job(
  input_val INT64)
AS
SELECT
  val,
  row2
FROM TableOfInterest
WHERE val = input_val;
```

This works great and returns the appropriate results for a single `input_val`. But I'd like to return multiple rows, one for each value of `input_val`.

by doing something like this pseudo-code

```
SELECT 
    val,
    row2
FROM
  Job(
    (
      SELECT
        val
      FROM ValTable
      LIMIT 100
    ))
```

My hope is to return 100 rows where each row gives me the appropriate results from `TableOfInterest` for the corresponding value of `input_val`.

An additional wrinkle, is that eventually I want to join against a second TVF that looks as follows

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE FUNCTION Job2(
  input_val INT64)
AS
SELECT
  val,
  row3
FROM TableOfInterest2
WHERE val = TIMESTAMP_FROM_UNIX_MICROS(input_val);
```

How can I pass each of these TVFs multiple values for `input_val` and get tables back?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48694268/1902480) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20235410/1902480) but they don't seem to address what I'm trying to do in BigQuery. Which feels pretty simple. Is it not?

I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious in the documentation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'd like to return multiple rows, one for each value of input_val.

Consider below:

Step 1 - create table function

```
CREATE TABLE FUNCTION project.dataset.Job(input_vals array<INT64>) AS (
  SELECT
    val,
    row2
  FROM TableOfInterest
  WHERE val IN UNNEST(input_vals)
);
```

Step 2 - use it :o)

```
SELECT 
    val,
    row2
FROM project.dataset.Job(
    ARRAY(
      SELECT val
      FROM ValTable
      LIMIT 100
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you! So I was just missing changing the input type to `array` and then `UNNEST`ing the array. Appreciate the help!

Comment: yes. you were quite close :o) also, have in mind  - temp table functions are not supported (at least as of now) :o)